# why the executing shell within cron job will take longer time than normal?

Tags: linux, shell-script, cron

I have a shell script which will run project consist of multiple JUnit tests.

Then I call this shell within cron job every a period of time. In this case, I observe the following:

- Time to complete executing this shell is longer than directly calling this shell.

I don't know why!?

They must have the same run time, mustn't they?

Comment: Probably cron run your process with a lower priority and it receives less cpu and memory resources.

Answer (score 0):

Your cron job is receiving less resources, you can run it with a higher priority with:

```
/usr/bin/nice --adjustment=-10 /path/to/cron-script
```

> Note the command above will reduce the resources of running services, so be
>   careful using in production services.